# Javascript loop in browser reloading page and accessing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm stuck with a javascript that repeatedly goes to a certain website (every couple of seconds) and once the page is loaded accesses the DOM.

In Pseudocode it would be something like this:

```
while(true)
 go to page Y (every X Seconds)
 wait until page Y is loaded (at least DOM)
 click on Button A on page Y (DOM Element)
end while
```

Maybe javascript in the browser is the wrong way to realize this, however as I'm able to do it manually I figured there might be a way.

```
location.href = 'http://url/of/page';
$(':Submit').click();
```

Shell scripting is (supposedly) hard to realize as I need the open browser session since I'm logged in on the page.
Maybe PHP is easier?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: PHP is a server side language—it can't trigger clicks for you.

Comment: Neither PHP or JS are suitable for what you describe. Is this for automated testing? If so, something like http://www.seleniumhq.org/ would be a better solution.

Comment: If this is for web testing, I'd definitely recommend Selenium. It's a fantastic tool, Robot Framework which is a framework that sits on top of Selenium is also absolutely fantastic!

Comment: Thank you, yes it is for web testing! Selenium looks great I'm trying to solve the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, this isn't exactly the most elegant thing you can do, actually it's pretty terrible. It's called framing, and I'm assuming you are using it on a site that you are developing or performing tests on, rather than using it for 'nefarious' things!

These steps are for Chrome, but you can perform the equivalent in Firefox, etc to much the same effect.

1) Navigate to your site, open the Developer Panel and select Elements.

2) Right-click on the `<HTML>` element and select Edit as HTML.

3) Press `Ctrl+A` and then `Del` or `Backspace` to delete everything.

4) Paste in the following:

```
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <iframe style="width:100%; height: 100%; border: 0px;"></iframe>
</body>
```

5) Open the Javascript Console and paste the following:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
iframe.onload = function()
{
    // Do whatever you need to do with the loaded page.
};
setInterval(function() { iframe.src = location.href; }, 10000);
// 10000 = 10 seconds, replace with whatever value you want.
```

Please code responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Progress Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/) to get DOM information. The example given in the documentation of Progress Events is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Waiting for Magical Unicorns</title>
<progress id="p"></progress>
<script>
  var progressBar = document.getElementById("p"),
      client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("GET", "magical-unicorns");
  client.onprogress = function(pe) {
    if(pe.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.max = pe.total;
      progressBar.value = pe.loaded;
    }
  }
  client.onloadend = function(pe) {
    progressBar.value = pe.loaded;
  }
  client.send();
</script>
```

All you would need to do is wait until the page is loaded and then go to whatever link you wanted like so: `window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")` with this second parameter to `open` you could even use the same browser window.